# Remap wires or simplify triangles?

Tags: modeling, rigging, wireframe

I'm working on a quick project for work where I need to turn an STEP file into an FBX for Blender, which I have done... However, now that it's in Blender I'm noticing some problems with its wireframe and things of that sort.

For one, the wireframe is really... messy? For lack of a better word. It has made the right shapes and amazing 3D model, but a lot of the triangles/polys are stretched and bundled together near pivot points-- I'll attach an image. There are too many, too close together, that aren't doing anything.

[image]

The other issue(s) come along with this. There are over 6 Million triangles. The file is huge. And there are 3000 objects, which I can join, but I'm throwing it in there to help make a point.

[image]

Is there any way for me to just... remap my model? Simplify the triangles? Please help out if you can, and thank you.

[image]

Comment: What you really need is a new topology, I don't know if I have finished cleaning your model but I doubt that it is so, the answer they gave you is not correct, I recommend you consider making a new model with a better topology, it will take you less time than cleaning 6 million TRIS

Answer (score 0):

First of all select your triangular mesh faces then press ALT+J for shortcut of 'Tris to Quads'. it can help you to solve some of triangles, for rest of tricky areas you have to do it manually.